# How to resize and rename images in bulk on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, images

I’ve about 300 images that I would need to resize all on the same size. Also, it would be nice to also nice to rename the resized images, so the original image is called `file1.png`, then the resized image as `file1_thumb.png`.

Could you recommend me, please, a tool for this task?

Answer (score 4):

Mac OS X ships with a utility called `sips` (Scriptable Image Processing System) that can also suit your needs. Say you wanted to resize your 300 images to one-half the size and renamed to *filename*_small.jpg

```
cd ~/Pictures/batchConvert
for x in ./*; do
   WIDTH=$(sips -g pixelWidth "$x"|grep pixelWidth|awk '{print $2/2}')
   sips --resampleWidth $WIDTH "$x" --out $(echo $x|sed s/.jpg/_small.jpg/)
done
```

In addition, `sips` can read/write picture properties, change the output format, flip horizontal/vertical and more. Check out the man page for `sips` for more ideas.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the great command line image processing tool, [ImageMagick](http://cactuslab.com/imagemagick/) and a `bash` script like this to resize and rename your files:

```
find '/full/path/to/your/pics' -type f -name '*.png' |\
  while read FILENAME
  do
    NEW_FILENAME="$(echo $FILENAME | sed 's/.png//g')"
    convert -density 72 -resize "200x200>" -quality 90% "${FILENAME}" "${NEW_FILENAME}"_thumb.png
  done
```

Of course, you would need to change `/full/path/to/your/pics` to match your actual image path. Then you can change the `convert` (ImageMagick tool) options like `-density`, `-resize` and `-quality` to best suit your needs.

You could also change the `_thumb.png` to match whatever new filename you wish to use. If you set that to `.png` it would simply overwrite your files in place with the newly converted files. Or if you change the extension to `.jpg` or `.gif` you would be telling ImageMagick to convert the `.png` file to a `.jpg` or `.gif`. The configuration options of ImageMagick are a world unto themselves so it might seem a bit daunting at first, but spend some time learning the ropes and it is a rewarding and powerful tool.

But if ImageMagick is too complex for you, then [“Graphic Converter”](http://www.lemkesoft.de/en/image-editing-slideshow-browser-batch-conversion-metadata-and-more-on-your-mac/) might be a better bet. It]s been around since the 1990s and is a great GUI tool for bulk image conversion and manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Automator.

*Create Thumbnail Images* can resize and add a name suffix, however the resizing options are fixed at 128, 96, and 72 pixels.

If you'd like a different size you could use *Scale Images* and *Rename Finder Items* set to *Add Text* after the name. Note that these actions affect the files directly, so you would want to create a copy of the original images first, which could be part of the automator workflow (and, in fact, will be suggested when you add those actions to your workflow--you only need to copy the files once at the start of the workflow, though Automator may ask you twice).

Comment: I'd add screenshots of example workflows, but I don't have the reputation for that yet. ):

Answer (score -1):

You can also do that (and a lot more) with an application, in case you are not comfortable with Automator or scripting via a program called [Photo Batch](https://www.oneperiodic.com/products/photobatch/).

It has lots of features (quoting from the website):

- Adjust image brightness, contrast and saturation.
- Crop your image by percentage or by pixels.
- Resize your image by percentage or by pixels.
- Rotate all images at once.
- Maintain image aspect ratio by setting the maximum pixel height or width.
- Export all images to the same folder, regardless of where they came from.
- Instantly rename all of your images.
- Convert images from all major file formats (jpeg, png or tiff).
- Preserve original metadata. Retina-ready graphics.